# What's this reverse site address naming system in Java?

Tags: java, package

Like `com.google.appengine.codelab.Util` [is a class](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html), but why does it look like that, like a reversed domain name of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Java's package naming conventions. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).